# Python app server & web server co-existing?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, python, fastcgi, wsgi

I have a site example.com that runs off a 'normal' web server ie at the moment Apache but looking to go for a less RAM intensive alternative in future so I don't want mod_WSGI on apache.

Shortly I will be looking to deploy a web app that runs out of a python app server. I want this answering all requests to example.com/reallycoolpythonwebapp/ with the web server looking after the rest.

How is such an architecture created? Am I looking to Pointers to relevant online docs are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you would run your python server on a different port, then make use of Apache's (or any decent webserver like nginx etc) reverse proxy functionality to reverse proxy any requests for example/com/reallycoolpythonwebapp to the python app server

this will also appear transparent to the user as well

some apache config within the example.com vhost might look like this assuming mod_proxy is installed and enabled

```
ProxyPass /reallycoolpythonwebapp/ http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse /reallycoolpythonwebapp/ http://localhost:3000/
<Proxy *>
allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Comment: I like this idea. I guess I'd just deploy the changes you describe to the web server, change the app server to accept only 127.0.0.1 connections and everything would work without change to the application?

Comment: thats correct and it adds a touch of security to your web app if you use any webserver security features like mod_security or http auth

Comment: prefer this idea instead of use a single python application server and keep all my apps running by separate.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably setup Apache to proxy requests to localhost:xyz (or whatever host/port your python app will be listening on) when the request matches example.com/reallycoolpythonwebapp/

You ought to be able to pull that off with a combination of mod_rewrite (to match the target URL) and mod_proxy.

Relevant Apache docs:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

In particular, in the second, note the table entries for:

> ^/somepath(.*) {url1}$1 [P] {url2}

Answer (score 0):

The most common answer is proxy. For starters `mod_proxy` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).